# Python to Arduino Serial Communication Yields Semi-random Results

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial, serial-communication, duplex

I am trying to get an Arduino to give data to Python form a sensor. Then when this data is received into Python, Python needs to send a signal back to the Arduino to get a motor to react to the incoming data. Presently my code results in this, however if I look at the data I will have random spikes of data that do not coincide with the scenario. For example I will place a 5 newton load on the sensor and it will read 5 newtons for several iterations, then it will spike to something that is random. I have looked at just the Arduino output in the Arduino IDE and it is a steady and constant stream of data. I have looked at what Python receives without having the out going signal and that gives the same thing as the Arduino. I don't know why when I have to two send information back and forth I get this issue. If anyone has a better solution on how to get good readings I would appreciate it.

**Python**

```
import serial
import csv
import time
import sys
from time import localtime, strftime
import warnings
import serial.tools.list_ports

__author__ = 'Matt Munn'

arduino_ports = [
    p.device
    for p in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
    if 'Arduino' in p.description
]
if not arduino_ports:
    raise IOError("No Arduino found - is it plugged in? If so, restart computer.")
if len(arduino_ports) > 1:
    warnings.warn('Multiple Arduinos found - using the first')

Arduino = serial.Serial(arduino_ports[0],9600,timeout=1)
time.sleep(2)
start_time=time.time()
Force = []
Actuator_Signal=[]
Cycle_Count=[]
state = True
Up = True
numPoints = 10
ForceList = [0]*numPoints
AvgForce = 0

#This allows the user to input test conditions.
Force_Input = input("What is the force you want to test with in Newtons?")
Cycles = input("How many cycles would you like to run?")
Material = input("What kind of material is to be tested?")
print("The test will be conducted with", Force_Input, " Newtons of force and for a total of" , Cycles, " cycles.", " on", Material)
print ("REMOVE HANDS AND OTHER OBJECTS AWAY FROM AREA OF OPERATION.")
print("Testing will begin.")
time.sleep(5)

start_time = time.time()
#This creates the unique file for saving test result data.
outputFileName =  "  Cycle_Pull_Test_#.csv"
outputFileName = outputFileName.replace("#", strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H %M %S", localtime()))


with open(outputFileName, 'w',newline='') as outfile:
    HeaderNames = ['Material','Newtons','Time']
    outfileWrite = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames = HeaderNames)
    outfileWrite.writeheader() 
#This takes the data from the arduino and interprits it.
    while True:

        while (Arduino.inWaiting()==0):
            pass
        try:
            data = Arduino.readline()
            dataarray = data.decode().rstrip().split(',')
            for i in range(0,numPoints):
                Force = abs(round(float(dataarray[0]),3))
                ForceList[i] = Force
                AvgForce = round((sum(ForceList)/numPoints),3)
                elapsed_time = round(time.time()-start_time,3)
                print (AvgForce, elapsed_time)

#This Controls the actuators direction based on the force input on the loadcell.

            if AvgForce > float(Force_Input):
                Up = False
                state = True 
                Arduino.write(b'd') 
            else: 
                Arduino.write(b'u')
                Up = True
            if state == True and Up == True:
                state = False
                Cycles = float(Cycles) + 1

            if Cycles >= float(Cycle_Count[0]):
                Arduino.write(b'o')
                print("Testing is done.")
                time.sleep(1) 
                sys.exit("All the data will be saved now")



        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit,IndexError,ValueError):
            pass
#This writes the data from the loadcell to a csv file for future use.
        outfileWrite.writerow({'Material' : Material, 'Newtons' : AvgForce, 'Time' :elapsed_time })
```

**Arduino**

```
#include <HX711_ADC.h> // HX711 Library
#include "CytronMotorDriver.h"

// Configure the motor driver.
CytronMD motor(PWM_DIR, 3, 2);  // PWM = Pin 3, DIR = Pin 2.

int up = HIGH;
int down = LOW;
int dstate = up;
int python_direction = 0;
float interval = 12000;
float pretime= 0;
float curtime = 0;

HX711_ADC LoadCell(11, 12);

float force;  
float calforce;
float newtons;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  LoadCell.begin();
  LoadCell.start(2000); // tare preciscion can be improved by adding a few seconds of stabilising time
  LoadCell.setCalFactor(100.0); // user set calibration factor (float)


}

void loop() {
  LoadCell.update();

  forceRead();
  actuatorControl();


}void forceRead()
{
  force = LoadCell.getData();
  force = (force/285); // Force in (N) // 285 is conversion factor
  calforce = (-1.0389*force)+0.0181, // This is in lbs
  newtons = 4.45*calforce;
  Serial.println(newtons);


  //receive from serial terminal for tare
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
  char inByte = Serial.read();
  if (inByte == 't') LoadCell.tareNoDelay();
  }
}

void actuatorControl(){

  if (Serial.available()>0){
    python_direction = Serial.read();
    Serial.print (python_direction);
    Serial.print (",");
  }
  if (python_direction == 'd'){
    motor.setSpeed(255);  // Run forward at full speed.

  }
  if (python_direction == 0){
    motor.setSpeed(0);  // Stop motor.

  }
  if (python_direction == 'u'){
    motor.setSpeed(-255);  // Run backward at full speed.


  }
}
```

Comment: It would probably help to write in a sanity check for received data: Having it print some debug information "Received from X: 123123123 newtons (too high)". Depending on your application, you could probably just discard the bad data.

Comment: I was considering that, and it would work for some numbers. Yet in some instances I get numbers that are in my operating range when I don't want them. Like say I have 5 newtons on and my range is 0 to 100, well it might say there is 87 newtons on there.

Comment: I was hoping to have a more robust solution that doesn't need some omit this because I know its wrong. I don't want any wrong numbers I guess.

Comment: Even if you aren't discarding the points, it should give you a better idea as to where the bad data is coming from. And you could have the cutoff adjust to the run. Unless you have some math error I don't expect we'll be able to help you much with figuring out where the erroneous data is starting.

Comment: It wouldn't be a math error if the numbers are fine when they are read in the arduino ide. The problem only happens after I implemented the python code that talks back to the arduino. Up until then all the numbers were correct and smooth. So clearly there is a problem between the two talking to one another. Maybe they are talking at the same time and that is the error. I don't however know how to get them to talk separately.